# How to create multiple different initializers that take no parameters in Swift

Tags: swift

In Objective-C we could have different initializers that did different things and took no arguments.

```
- (instancetype) initForSomethingSpecific;
- (instancetype) initWithDefaultSettings;
```

So you could call them as

```
[[MyClass alloc] initForSomethingSpecific];
[[MyClass alloc] initWithDefaultSettings];
```

These type of initializers get translated in Swift as

```
init(forSomethingSpecific: ())
init(defaultSettings: ())
```

so they can be called as

```
MyClass(forSomethingSpecific: ())
MyClass(defaultSettings: ())
```

but this doesn't look very *swifty*.

Is there a correct way to do this in a Swift-only environment? Are factory methods preferred?

Thank you.

Comment: Usually, factory methods are used, yeah.

Comment: looks strange in Objective-C, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The factual side of this is there doesn't seem to be a way to do this with swift.

My personal understanding/opinion is the that purpose of an init method in Swift is to create an object with default characteristics, or with the information passed to it in the initializer. If you're instantiating an object for some specific configuration in an initializer, that's really a factory placed in an initializer, not a true initializer per se.

Comment: All of the old Cocoa Objective-C inits were transformed into Swift class factories. Probably worth illustrating in your answer...